# How to check if a stylesheet is already loaded?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, css

I was wondering how to check if a css file is already loaded. For example, I have in my theme Font Awesome `font-awesome.min.css` and I have a plugin that make use of Font Awesome too. So, I ended up with two `font-awesome.min.css` stylesheets loaded. Is there a way to check if a CSS sheet is already loaded before I enqueue it.

Comment: you can when styles are added in the proper way: using `wp_enqueue_style`, if the css is inserted with a `<link rel="stylesheet" ...` you can't.

Comment: They are both added properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've +1 the Ravs answer because it it good and it should works in most case, however it assumes that you know the handle used by 3rd party theme/plugins and this is not always true.

If all developer used same handle for same styles/scripts the problem does not exists, because **WordPress automatically skip styles and scripts registered with same handle**.

But let's assume you register the css using:

```
wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', ... );
```

and another plugin use

```
wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome', ... );
```

WordPress will load file 2 times.

In most cases developer tend to use just the name of the css without extension, but this is not a rule and also can be different version, e.g.

```
wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome.min', ... );
```

An alternative aproach is lookin at the file names of registered script, looking at global `$wp_styles` that contain an arrays of all the registered scripts, something like:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'check_font_awesome', 99999);

function check_font_awesome() {
  global $wp_styles;
  $srcs = array_map('basename', (array) wp_list_pluck($wp_styles->registered, 'src') );
  if ( in_array('font-awesome.css', $srcs) || in_array('font-awesome.min.css', $srcs)  ) {
    /* echo 'font-awesome.css registered'; */
  } else {
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/font-awesome.css' );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can stop loading multiple font-awesome.min.css:

1).use same handle as in you plugin used to enqueue/register font-awesome.min.css. ( by this way WordPress does not load multiple font-awesome.min.css files )

or

2).you can also use to check css file loaded or not via [wp_style_is()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_style_is)

```
<?php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','ravs_check_FA_status',999);  // 3rd parameter should be max mean apply this action when all scripts or styles loaded, show we can check easily font-awesome.min.css loaded or not
function ravs_check_FA_status(){
if( wp_style_is( $handle, $list = 'enqueued' ) ){ // $handle = Name of the style in your plugin
  //code
}else{

//code
}
?>
```